# Showing a linear map is a derivation at a point iff it vanishes on the rank 0 map

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds, tangent-spaces

I am again having a hard time solving an "easy" exercise of the lecture note by Ed Segal on the theory of manifold. ([http://www.homepages.ucl.ac.uk/~ucaheps/papers/Manifolds%202016.pdf](http://www.homepages.ucl.ac.uk/%7Eucaheps/papers/Manifolds%202016.pdf))

The elaborated statement is as follows.

$\bullet$ A linear map $\partial : C^\infty(X)\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is a derivation at $x$ iff $\partial$ vanishes on the subspace $R_x(X)\subset C^\infty(X)$ of functions having rank zero at $x$.

The definition of a derivation at $x$ is a linear map $\partial : C^\infty(X) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ obeying a Leibniz product rule.

Could somebody please prove the "if" part of the above proposition?

Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: What does it mean rank zero at x?

Comment: @FedericoFallucca It means the Jacobian of a certain map evaluated at $x$ has rank zero.

Comment: Did you try anything?

Comment: @ArcticChar Actually, the only way that came up with my mind is to Taylor expand two functions which did not work. Could you give me a hint on solving the problem? The question is not for a college homework or sort of...

Comment: May be the function $(fg)(y) - f(x) g(y) - f(y) g(x)$ (with $x$ fixed) has rank zero at $x$?

Comment: @ArcticChar Oh, that clearly resolves the problem. Thank you so much!